# Proper way to Update TableView when adding / deleting

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a list of bluetooth devices that can be turned off and on. When on they appear in the tableview and get removed when turned off. My bluetooth manager object contains the device list and whenever the list is updated a notification is triggered to update the tableview. Adding doesn't seem to be a problem, those appear instantly, but when I remove something from the list it doesn't seem to get removed from the tableview.

Is this expected behavior or does updating the tableview not work with this method?

```
private void DeviceCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    updateDevices();
}

private void updateDevices()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Update in iOS");
    deviceTable.Source = new DeviceTableSource(bleHandler.getModelList().ToList());
    deviceTable.ReloadData();
}
```

I know reloading isn't optimal as it redraws the entire table but the list is limited to 6 devices and shouldn't change very often.

Comment: This can reload data immediately, you can try to change the list's value in your source instead of setting `Source` every time.

Comment: I updated it to change the list value instead of creating a new source. Didn't fix the problem but better than the way I was doing it before thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to get it to remove correctly. It came down to a threading issue.

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    deviceTable.ReloadData();
});
```